# Projecting image of a flat (originally 3D) sphere texture onto 3D round cube

Tags: uv

I'm trying to remake these flat early 2000s chat client smilies in 3D:

[image: Smilies]

What I've done so far: add a round cube, add a subdivision modifier, add the image as a texture, and UV unwrap using "Project From View". It's added to the object and the eyes are projected on to the exact spot they need to be. It looks exactly as the original image does, more or less.

[image: Projected from view]

I want to be able to draw on the back of the smiley and quickly edit designs in Photoshop.

Is there a way to take this "Project From View" UV projection and manipulate the originally given texture into a UV projection that is more manageable and customizable, like one I would get when using smart unwrap with a seam on the back.

[image: Sample UV Projection]

In the end, I would like it to look like a [standard head unwrapping](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b2/44/ca/b244ca9f645e1c8cf5f365e8f1c73123.jpg).

My example is simple and I could just quickly draw them in the UV projection I'm aiming for, but there are more complicated designs I'll eventually use this process with.

I'm lost at trying to describe/ask this question so please bare with me. Thank you.

Comment: if you want to change the UVs you can create a second UV unwrap and bake your texture onto another image texture

Comment: @moonboots I didn't know you could create a second UV unwrap! Thanks so much. I didn't have the right words to even be able to search for a tutorial. I followed this tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HyexrUEIv0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to change the UVs you can create a second UV unwrap and bake your texture onto another image texture.

[image]

If you ever need to use several UV maps in the same material, you can use an *Input > UV Map* node.